# Ionic capacitor/firebase app, fcm message received on emulator but not on a real device

Tags: firebase, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor, mobile-development

[image]

Check this screenshot.

I have literally checked everything I can think of:

- Via built apk on the real devices (yes, in plural) and on emulator: message received on emulators but not on devices
- Or via android studio to device/emulator connected to pc: same as above
- Sent by my code: by fcm or by topic -> Worked on emulator but not on device
- Sent from firebase console (new notification -> Send Test Message): Same as above.

as if the real devices are blocking them from the source; I have checked Settings -> Notifications -> app and it is allowed

And yes, I have checked the package name matches with my firebase's package name; anyway it shouldn't work on emulator either if there's any misconfiguration, right?

This is my manifest

[image]

Edit:
Even on the android studio's emulator it is working (and not just on bluestack):

[image]

I am totally baffled!

Comment: have you tried with release build or only debug? and have you tried on different devices?

Comment: @AmirAliSaghaei
I have tried with Build -> Build APK, which creates a app-debug.apk,   I installed on two devices and on two emulators, only the emulators receive the fcms. Why this would make any difference?

Comment: I had some issues with debug/release build for devices of Android 12+, try it with build variant set to release and check if it works. it should create app-release.apk